# ArcGIS file export

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, export, png, jpg

Am having issues exporting a Layout Map of an area from ArcGIS to any raster format (JPEG, TIFF and PNG).

The map gets partially exported with no errors reported.

Exporting to PDF works fine.

My map consists wholly of Vectors and other maps with exactly the same vector files export just fine.

Does anyone have a solution to this or a suggestion on how to circumvent it?

Comment: are there any errors present when exporting? Exporting directly to a raster from ArcMAP is not the best idea, generally exporting to PDF with a higher DPI will result in better quality. From there you can export PDF to PNG, or any format you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem on my own. Apparently ArGIS was having memory deficits. I simply increased the allocated Memory.